# Trying to get analytics on Microsoft teams calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to put together analytics on Microsoft teams calls. I would like to get hold times, number of transfers, call time, etc. I came across this call https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords and it gives me a list of calls with call times, but I can't find a way to get hold times, what line it came in on, etc. Greatly appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this end point https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/communications/callRecords only allows you to query a single call record using its ID, it does not support querying a list of call records for the whole tenant or for a specific user.

The only way currently to find this ID to query the call record is by setting up a web hook to receive change notifications. Refer to the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks) for more info on change notifications.

To directly address your question, i am not one hundred percent sure but i believe the information you're looking for could be found inside the list of [sessions and segments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-session-list?view=graph-rest-beta) inside a call record.